# rsync: send_files failed to open "filename": Invalid argument (22)

Tags: rsync

I use rsync to copy files from a mounted davfs box.com folder to an ext4 partition. For files containing the symbols [, ", and {, I receive the following error:

> rsync: send_files failed to open "filename containing [ or " or {": Invalid argument (22)

The command I run is:
`rsync -aviP source destination >> rsync.out`

Is there a native rsync method for handling this?